# React map why two infowindows appear after click a marker

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, marker, infowindow, react-google-maps

I really don't understand why two infowindows appear after clicking a marker, the weird thing is sometimes in inspection mode infowindow appear normally. I'm wondering if the callback cause the problem. Code are below:

```
import { GoogleMap, Marker,withGoogleMap,withScriptjs, InfoWindow } from "react-google-maps";
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'
import React, { Component } from 'react'

const API_KEY = 'INSERT_API_KEY'

const MyMapComponent = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap((props) =>
            <GoogleMap
                defaultZoom={8}
                defaultCenter={{ lat: -33.897, lng: 151.144 }}
                
            >  
                {props.locs.map((location)=>{
                    const onMarkerClick = props.onMarkerClick.bind(this,location)
                    return <Marker 
                            key={nanoid()}
                            position={location}
                            onClick={onMarkerClick}>
                            </Marker>
                            
                })}
                {props.showingInfoWindow && 
                    <InfoWindow position={props.activeMarker} onCloseClick={props.markerInfoClose}>
                        <h1>Details</h1>
                    </InfoWindow>}
            </GoogleMap>
            ));

export default class Test extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            locations:[{lat: -33.865143,lng: 151.2},],
            showingInfoWindow: false,
            activeMarker: {}, 
        };
    }
    onMarkerClick = (location) =>{
        this.setState({
            activeMarker: location,
            showingInfoWindow: true
        });
    }
    onClose = () => {
        if (this.state.showingInfoWindow) {
            this.setState({
                activeMarker: null,
                showingInfoWindow: false
            });
        }
    };
    render() {
        console.log(this.state.activeMarker)
        return (
            <div>
                <MyMapComponent
                    locs={this.state.locations}
                    onMarkerClick={this.onMarkerClick}
                    showingInfoWindow={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
                    activeMarker={this.state.activeMarker}
                    markerInfoClose={this.onClose}
                    containerElement={ <div style={{ height: `1000px`, width: '1000px' }} /> } 
                    mapElement={ <div style={{ height: `100%` }} /> }
                    loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
                    googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=${API_KEY}`}
                >

                </MyMapComponent>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

ScreenShoot:
[image]

Comment: I tried running your code and I can't seem to replicate the issue where 2 infowindow are generated. I can only see one. Also, the image link you provided seems to be broken. Lastly, I removed the API key you included in your question. Please don't post your API key in public sites like StackOverflow in the future.

Comment: Ooops, the image link is not broken but here's the [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-2infowindow-8swjjf?file=Map.js) that shows only 1 infowindow.